# Why can we apply the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to prove that $C(K)$ is separable when $K$ is compact?

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces

I am looking at the second part of Lemma 3.102 in here:

[Banach Space Theory, by Fabian, M. *et al.*](https://books.google.co.cr/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=When%20is%20the%20space%20C(K)%20separable&source=bl&ots=4dxUF-FzVx&sig=otZYEjS3nfKk7y8s1FBgFTIPAAo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aGzvUtaBF-biyAGMs4CoCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=When%20is%20the%20space%20C(K)%20separable&f=false)

I understand how the Stone-Weierstrass theorem can be applied to the subalgebra described by the authors (let us call it $A$), but I do not understand how this proves the statement that $C(K)$ is separable. According to my understanding, $C(K)$ would be separable if it had a dense numerable subset. However, in the case where the field over which we work is uncountable (for example, $\mathbb{C}$), the fact that we can consider any linear combination as a member of $A$ makes the cardinality of $A$ to be uncountable. So then $A$ is dense, but it is not the numerable subset we are looking for, right?

Am I missing some additional theorem/lemma here?

EDIT: Here is the link again, as some people said it wasn't working for them: https://books.google.co.cr/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128%C2%BF#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I can see nothing from the link. Please, add the relevant material.

Comment: Polynomials are dense in $C([0,1].$ Therefore polynomials with rational coefficients are dense in $C([0,1].$ The latter is a countable set. It's that kind of thing ...

Comment: @egreg I added the link again.

Comment: “You have either reached a page that is unavailable for reading or reached your viewing limit for this book”. Without context (what's $K$?) you'll only get generic answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe @zhw's comment answers correctly my question. The polynomials with rational coefficients are dense in the algebra I called $A$. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I believe here the field is $\mathbb{R}$ you can consider the $\mathbb{Q}$- linear combinations of the functions $f_{n,m}$ which is numerable and dense.